# How to create a vertical scatter graph using range specific abscissas using Sigmaplot

Tags: range, axes, scatter, sigmaplot

I am currently working on a project in which I will be creating a vertical scatter plot using on average 6 points of y-axis data using Sigmaplot. The units of the graph are depth of snow in cm vs time. However the data I have collected is gathered over a range of days (i.e. 173-176) and I am having trouble applying my data sets to their respective ranged abscissa. I've noticed inputting the data in this manner finds the difference in the abscissa (i.e. 173-176 would correspond to 3) rather than interpreting the data as a range. Can anyone help me find a way in which to input abscissa not as singular values but rather ranges of those values using Sigmaplot?

Comment: Also, if there is some means of scaling the scatter points to be as wide as the time range? It's tricky and limiting to use this interface, Sigmaplot, I may be asking too much..

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the abscissa ranges in tact, plot all of the data. Sigmaplot does not want sort these data and rather places them in their respective chronological order.  I did not find a way to make the width of the points as wide as the abscissa.